# Extraer el nombre de las columnas con Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Acabo de empezar con hibernate y me gustaria obtener el nombre de las columnas de mi base de datos a través de Hibernate, almacenar dichos nombres en una variable y no se como. Tengo configurado el XML asi:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 5.3//EN"  
     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-5.3.dtd">   
     <hibernate-mapping>  
     <class name="Avisos.Aviso" table="Aviso">  
        <id name="destinatario" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="Destinatario" />
        </id>
        <property name="remitente" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="Remitente" />
        </property>
        <property name="asunto" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="Asunto" />
        </property>
        <property name="mensaje" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="Mensaje" />
        </property>
        <property name="fecha_envio" type="java.util.Date" access="field">
            <column name="Fecha_Envio" />
        </property>
        <property name="leido" type="java.lang.Boolean" access="field">
            <column name="Leido" />
        </property>
     </class>             
     </hibernate-mapping>
```

y otro xml llamado hibernate.cfg.xml que es el que accede a él para mapearlo.

Me gustaría acceder directamente a este xml para obtener el column name de las property, o a través de una consulta o alguna otra forma.

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

Conseguí extraerlas de los POJOS con este método:

```
String[] columnNames = SessionFactory.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Jaula.class).getPropertyNames();
```

Funciona pero esta Deprecated

Comment: Creaste los POJOS? O sea las Clases que se generan con las Tablas de la base de datos?

Comment: Para qué necesitas conocer los nombres de las columnas? Por qué en vez de usar archivos XML para configurar el mapeo no usas anotaciones?

Comment: Si, cree clases que asocio a las tablas de la base de datos. Respondiendo a E.Betanzos, necesito extraer los nombres para añadirlos a un DefaultTableModel como cabecera, y use los XML siguiendo el tutorial de Hibernate que descargué.